# I'm stuck with some reflection in my Java project

Tags: java, reflection

I've been working on a Bukkit plugin project for a while, and I've finally decided to make a formal release.  So in my crazy scramble to document everything about my project, I decided to clean up some APIs for people that would like to use them.  Now, I've hit the wall with a single problem though.

Basically, in this API, you must implement an interface and then register your implementation with a class that manages every implementation and also checks for/registers another variable with the PluginMetrics that are bundled inside the plugin.

Here is my interface, with the "name" and "tracker" fields being fields of concern:

```
public interface IAction {

    /**
     * Name of the action.
     */
    String name = null;
    /**
     * Stores args passed to the action by the player.
     */
    String[] args = null;
    /**
     * Holds the Metrics tracker object.
     */
    Tracker tracker = null;

    ...
}
```

And, here is the method (and init() method) where all my issues arise:

```
public static void registerAction(final Class a) {
    try {
        store.put((String) a.getField("name").get(a), a);
        log.exDebug(String.format("Action %s (%s) was registered.", (String) a.getField("name").get(a), a.getCanonicalName()));
        try {
            Tracker metric = (Tracker) a.getField("tracker").get(a);
            try {
                OpenAuth.getMetrics().addCustomData(metric);
                log.exDebug(String.format("Registered Metrics data tracker [%s] from %s.", metric.getColumnName(), a.getCanonicalName()));
            } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
                log.info("Exception occurred while registering Action data tracker.");
            }
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occurred while registering Action data tracker.");
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception occurred while registering an Action.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void init() {
    for (Actions a : Actions.values()) {
        try {
            registerAction(a.getAction());
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occurred while initialising Actions enumerator.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (Object ob : classLoader.load().getClasses()) {
        Class c = null;
        try {
            c = (Class) ob;
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occurred while casting up external Action.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            registerAction(c);
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occurred while registering external Action.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And an example implementation:

```
public class FreezeStick implements IAction {

    public static final String name = "freeze";
    public static final Tracker tracker = new Tracker("FreezeStick");

    private String[] args = null;
    private Session attached;
    private SessionController sc;
    private final LogHandler log = new LogHandler();
    private final String permissible = "openauth.action.freeze";
    private OAServer server;
    private boolean used = false;

    protected OAPlayer sender;
    protected OAPlayer target;

    public FreezeStick(OAServer server, Session attached) {
        this.server = server;
        this.sc = server.getController().getSessionController();
        this.attached = attached;
        this.setSender(this.attached.getPlayer());
    }

-- etc.. --
```

Every time `Tracker metric = (Tracker) a.getDeclaredField("tracker").get(a);` happens, it's
reported as `null`. I've tried with a.getField() instead of a.getDeclaredField(), but same problem. Both the name and tracker variables receive `private, static, and final` when they are declared in the implementations, and using a.getField() on the name variable has worked fine ever since I first wrote this.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Also, here is the exception that occurs if it helps with figuring out my problem any better:

```
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [INFO] [OpenAuth-debug] Action ban (me.maiome.openauth.actions.BanStick) was registered.
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [INFO] [OpenAuth] Exception occurred while adding Action data tracker.
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE] java.lang.NullPointerException
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at me.maiome.openauth.actions.Actions.registerAction(Actions.java:65)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at me.maiome.openauth.actions.Actions.init(Actions.java:104)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at me.maiome.openauth.bukkit.OpenAuth.onEnable(OpenAuth.java:230)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:381)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:278)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:260)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:214)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:52)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:11)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:104)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:399)
2013-01-02 10:48:10 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:849)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Turns out, I was trying to run #addCustomData() on the Metrics instance before there was Metrics instance ready to be used.  Just had to move Actions.init() down a few lines in my controller :)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot declare fields, is that the actual code?

The issue you are facing is that the `getDeclaredField` method will get a field with that given name, but will not search superclasses. To answer the reflection part of the question I suggest you create a helper method which would continually invoke `.getSuperclass()` on the Class object (and on that object's superclass, etc) until you reach a class that declares that field.
(Edit, to match the given example: To get static fields, you should use `field.get(null);`.)

A more appropriate solution, however, would be to make the interface declare some getter methods - `Tracker getTracker();` and `String getName();`.

Comment: Well, thing is, the registerAction() method is able to get the name completely fine! But every time the method tries to get the method tries to get the tracker, it gives a null.  Would it help clarify if I gave my entire Actions API?

Comment: If ```getDeclaredField``` is not the one returning ```null```, but ```get``` is, then it's likely that the value of the field actually is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with class objects that are structured as beans then you should take a look at BeanUtils in apache-commons or BeanWrapper (Not 100% sure on the name) in spring.  Behind the scenes they handle low level reflection and introspection for you so all you have to do is write a simple method call to retrieve a value.

Looking registerAction, you just try casting the passed in class object which might cause some head aches down stream.

I think you might be able to rewrite using generics to force an argument to be a Tracker class object

```
public static void registerAction(final Class<Tracker> a) {
```

You could also add a few checks to see if a class contains a method or field before you try using them.